# OVERLAPPABLE instance resolved rather than OVERLAPPING

Tags: haskell

I have an OVERLAPPABLE instance in one module:

```
class CompilerState s where

  recover :: s -> s -> Maybe s

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} CompilerState x where
  recover old new = trace "recover using default impl" $ Just old
```

and an OVERLAPPING instance in another:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} CompilerState (MyState u e) where
  recover old new
    = trace "using OVERLAPPING" $ Just old
```

Debugging my code reveales that GHC is using the OVERLAPPABLE instance rather than the OVERLAPPING instance in the client code (a third module)... Both relevant modules are imported, albeit the one with the OVERLAPPING instance is imported from a module that reexports the module with the OVERLAPPING instance. What could hinder GHC from resolving the "correct" instance? (The OVERLAPPING one)

Comment: I hope you have deeply considered whether you really need overlapping instances at all... IMO they're just not worth the trouble.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please provide more info. How are you using the `recover` function? How is `MyState` defined?

Comment: When this happens it's because at the site where the instance needs to be selected, GHC doesn't have information that narrows things to the overlapping case. Overlapping instances don't give runtime dispatch.

Comment: The described behavior should not be possible, and the explanation offered by @Carl should only apply if you have enabled the very dangerous `IncoherentInstances` extension.  You will probably need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get an answer to this question.

Comment: in the end I continued by removing the overlappable instance... If I find the time, I'll try creating a minimal reproducible example... and maybe it did happen, because I've forgotten to remove IncoherentInstances in one of my modules (have used it in the past) but rn I cannot tell...